# Strange difference between sequence and list in F#

Tags: xaml, f#

I have encountered strange issue with lists in F#.
I am using XamlXmlReader to generate list and sequence like:

```
let xaml_reader = XamlXmlReader(filename)
let nodes_seqs = seq { while xaml_reader.Read() do yield xaml_reader }
```

This code is working perfectly but if I do the same with list:

```
let xaml_reader2 = XamlXmlReader(filename)
let nodes_list = [ while xaml_reader2.Read() do yield xaml_reader2 ]
```

The result list is not correct i.e. head element of the sequence contains correct NodeType, LinePosition, LineNumber etc but head element of the list is kind of garbage with pointing to another place in XAML. Example:

```
let head_of_seq = Seq.head nodes_seq
let head_of_list = List.head nodes_list
```

After I have:

- head_of_seq.NodeType = NamespaceDeclaration
- head_of_seq.LineNumber = 2
- head_of_seq.LinePosition = 2

But:

- head_of_list.NodeType = None
- head_of_list.LineNumber = 111
- head_of_list.LinePosition = 30

XAML file itself is correct and generated by Microsoft Bend. Any clues? I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you yielding the `XamlXmlReader` itself from within your sequence or list?  That is, shouldn't you be using `yield xaml_reader.Value` instead?

In either case, you just end up with a sequence (or list) containing the same `XamlXmlReader` instance many times.  When you iterate over the sequence once, it will appear to be correct, since the reader is being advanced once as each element is read.  However, even your sequence is almost certainly not doing what you think.  For instance, what happens if you try this?

```
let first = Seq.head nodes_seqs
let first2 = Seq.head nodes_seqs
```

Because the `XamlXmlReader` is being advanced each time the sequence is accessed, `first2` will appear to be pointing at the second element (and looking at `first` after `first2` has been evaluated will show the same thing).

Comment: Because I am building AST from XAML and I need NodeType, Member, Value afterwards.
But it seems I understood the root cause of the issue. It has related to the fact that list contains references to XamlXmlReader nodes and value has changed each time when I step through.

Comment: Thanks kvb, you've enlightened me.

Comment: I don't know enough about these APIs, but you might just be able to yield a tuple of (r.NodeType, r.Value, ...) and be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, List is pinned-down, while Sequence is lazily-evaluated.  The best way to pin-down a sequence is to take a few elements, and call toList() on that.

I would recommend to try using XElement and related classes from System.Linq.XML namespace, then transition to XAML reader once you're comfortable there.

Comment: I've tried to convert sequence to list like:

let lst = Seq.toList nodes_seq

But in the result list elements are incorrect as well.

Comment: I think your approach to grab head element is correct.  In a sense, it pins down one element of sequence.  I have learned something today.  Good question!